# Three Column DIV layout dynamics; left = fixed, center = fluid, right = fluid

Tags: css, layout, html

The best solution I found so far was:

http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/UUzE9/

But that wasn't quite it. You see, I have three columns; two of which need to avoid being explicitly sized. Well, the second one does need to be sized; but not quite.

Allow me to clarify by establishing the conditions I've been trying to meet.

- All three columns have fixed height: 65px, to be precise.
- The first column's width is set to 285px.
- The center column has no size defined; it simply takes up whatever space is left.
- The right column will size itself to whatever content is in there. There is no size explicitly set, it simply resizes based on content, leaving the center column to take up whatever space is left.
- There is no whitespace above, below, and in between each column.

The end result would roughly look something like this:

```
   Logo     |            Player          |    Name     
-----------------------------------------------------
```

For tables, I'd have simply done this:

```
<table width="100%" height="65px" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr>
        <td width="285px" height="65px">
            Logo
        </td>
        <td height="65px">
            Player
        </td>
        <td width="1px" height="65px">
            Account
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Result of above table code: http://jsfiddle.net/zMNYb/

But I'm trying to move away from using tables and using a DIV-based layout.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could do div, div, span?

Comment: This post is very old. For recent tech please search for "css3 multiple columns"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this by using `float:left` for first column, `float:right` for the last column and making the center column `float:none`

Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L85rp/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="col1">Column1</div>
<div class="col3">Column3</div>
<div class="col2">Column2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col1 {
    background-color: #ddf;
    float: left;
}
.col2 {
    background-color: #dfd;
    float: none;
}
.col3 {
    background-color: #fdd;
    float: right;
}
```

---

**NOTE**: It is necessary to place your right column before your center column in HTML (see above, col3 comes before col2 in the HTML) to make sure that when the browser renders the center column, it knows how to render correctly around the existing floating elements.

---

**Updated CSS**

```
.col1 {
    background-color: #ddf;
    float: left;
    width: 285px;
    height: 65px;
}
.col2 {
    background-color: green;
    float: none;
    height: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-cell; /* turn this off to lock height at 65px */
}
.col3 {
    background-color: cyan;
    float: right;
    height: 65px;
}
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ew65G/1/

Comment: Interesting; why would it behave as such (shifting third DIV to the center when it's the third)?

Comment: Please see the note section in my answer. This is so that by the time the browser renders the non-floating column, it knows enough about the already existing floating columns and can correctly render the non-floating element around them. But yeah, this is pretty weird! :-)

Comment: Just ran the code with Chrome Browser's Inspector, and highlighted the center column. It seems that the reason why it's "aligned" in the center is that it's actually taking up *all* of the space from left to right-- as in the DIV is being layered *under* the left and right DIV's. The end result is anything placed in that DIV will break the layout. See example of breakage: http://jsfiddle.net/qxzBg/

Comment: In the CSS for col2, you can turn off `display: table-cell`, if you want your center column locked at `65px` height

Comment: Noticed overflow: hidden; is used. Commenting it out seemed to not make a difference. May I inquire as to why you chose to employ that property?

Comment: That is to cut off the center div at 65px height if you decide to turn off `display: table-cell` :) Otherwise its not needed.

Comment: Thank you for your most excellent assistance! For StackFlow, would you mind editing your solution to show the final solution? :)

Comment: Hi, @techfoobar If you have less text, like I showed here: http://clip2net.com/s/3cenQO9 the middle div is not completeing the rest of the space before the right one.

Comment: This is a bad implementation. Make the browser width narrow enough and you will see why.

Comment: Why do column heights change?

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by nested div concept. All you  need to do is divide the div section which you want as 3 columns as follows

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="column-1"></div>
    <div id="column-2">
        <div id="column-2-1"></div>
        <div id="column-2-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please go through [How to create 3 column layout using css div](http://www.gitarani.com/classified.htm?classifiedId=11540) to know more about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float:left; width:33%">Column1</div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%">Column2</div>
<div style="float:right; width:33%">Column3</div>
```

You can adjust width %  as required.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to put  "display:inline;" as a div normally displays in block form. Without the inline it will appear as three rows and not three columns.