# Three-Column Layout... left (fixed px), center (50%), right (50%)

Tags: css, layout, html

I want the left column to be 40px. I want the center column to be 50% of the remaining viewport and I want the right column to be the other 50% of the remaining viewport.

It should look something like this:

```
[LEFTCOLUMN][...CENTER COLUMN...][...RIGHT COLUMN....]
[...40px...][........50%........][........50%........]
```

The solution presented here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389588/three-column-div-layout-dynamics-left-fixed-center-fluid-right-fluid)) will not work for my case as the center column can become too collapsed on mobile devices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/KR9zj/

Essentially the trick is to float LEFTCOLUMN, and wrap both CENTERCOLUMN AND RIGHTCOLUMN in a wrapper with `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Yep. This solution worked out of the box. Thanks for your help, Shawn. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;`. No need to struggle with `float:x;`.

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='first'>a</div>
    <div id='second' class='fifty'>b</div>
    <div id='third' class='fifty'>c</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#container { display:table; width:100%; }
#container > * { display:table-cell; }
#first { width:40px; min-width:40px; }
#container .fifty { width:50%; }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/j25wK/

Comment: This solution will not work if there is a span tag (for example) inside the second or third div due to the #container > * declaration. I tried applying table-cell to second and third manually, but it did not line up correctly.

Comment: Although, I should mention... it does look the cleanest CSS wise. I tested your solution first :)

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/BVhCZ/

As you can see, the left is absolute, and "remaining" is one block div that containing two 50% floated children. Should work for any width >~ 40px

Code:

```
<div class="left">LEFT</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-left">CONTENT LEFT</div>
    <div class="content-right">CONTENT RIGHT</div>
</div>

.left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;    
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.content {
    margin-left: 40px;    
}
.content .content-left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    clear: none;
    background-color: #fdd;
}
.content .content-right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    clear: none;   
    background-color: #ddf;
}
```

Comment: This solution will not work because you're absolute positioning the left class to 0,0, which means nothing can go above that div.