# Center Column Responsive

Tags: html, css

I was trying to do what they did here: [Three Column DIV layout dynamics; left = fixed, center = fluid, right = fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389588/three-column-div-layout-dynamics-left-fixed-center-fluid-right-fluid)

It kind of works, but the center column doesn't fill the center, I do this:

HTML:

```
<div class="col1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="col2">
    <textarea class="aTextArea"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col1{
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.col2{
    display:inline;
    float: none;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.col3{
    display:inline;
    float: right;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.aTextArea{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

The desired effect is to have the textarea in the center fill the center. Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zbk6L/

Comment: not quite, trying to get the text area to fill all of the space in the middle, kind of like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zbk6L/2/

Comment: I can do this in JS, but I figure there's a better way of doing it in css that will be nice and smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Responsive and Perfect Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/cpp93/):**

**CSS**:

```
.col1 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* It alters the default CSS box model used to calculate widths and heights of elements. */
}

.col2 {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 30px;
}

.col3 {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aTextArea{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* New line added - Demo Updated */
    padding: 15px; /* New line added - Demo Updated*/
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">

    <div class="col1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="col3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30.jpg" />
    </div>    

    <div class="col2">
        <textarea class="aTextArea"></textarea>
    </div>

</div>
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cpp93/)

Answer (score 1):

your css and html structure should be like this

**css**

```
.col1{
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100px;
}
.col2{
    float: none;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:0 110px;
}
.col3{
    display:inline;
    float: right;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="col1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="col3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="col2">
    <textarea class="aTextArea"></textarea>
</div>
```

**[updated jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/zbk6L/10/)**

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a completely different approach like this: [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mdw2X/)

By setting the parent element to `display:table` and the children elements to `table-cell`, you can have the middle column occupy a width of `100%` and filling the remaining space.

```
#parent {
    display:table;
}
#parent > div {
    display:table-cell;
}
#parent > .col2, #parent > .col2 textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Despite the lack of [support in IE7](http://caniuse.com/css-table), this is an optimal solution because it works for elements of varying dimensions. You don't have to worry about collapsing content either, as floating elements aren't used, nor is the box model being changed.

Comment: This does it exactly the way I was trying to do it!

Answer (score 1):

I would use floats.

```
.col1, .col2, .col3 {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.col1{
width:20%;
}
.col2{
width:60%;
    text-align:center;
}
.col3{
width:20%;
text-align:right;
}
.aTextArea{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fSK9c/

If you really want your borders, I suggest using Outline, because border will break the layout.

```
outline:1px solid black;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YYnXt/