# DIV POSITIONING on right and left side

Tags: css, positioning

Am new to html and css I want to build a page with 3layouts right side left side and middle part will be content 
My question is how to place a divs on right and left side
I tried APdiv in dreamweaver but it is overlaping 
plz give me a solution

Comment: Use `float` TRY - http://jsfiddle.net/ezmsr9c9/

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389588/three-column-div-layout-dynamics-left-fixed-center-fluid-right-fluid)

Comment: use display:inline-block http://jsfiddle.net/fsrvyxqe/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
float:left;
```

for left,

```
float:right;
```

for right. And search before, ask you can find easily this questions answer on the net.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing 3 column web page:

HTML:

```
...

<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="left">LEFT</div>
  <div id="center">CENTER</div>
  <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
 </div>
</body>

...
```

CSS:

```
#container{
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden; /* This is not to overlap */
}

#left{
 width: 200px;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
}

#center{
 width: 560px;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
}

#right{
 width: 200px;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: green;
 float: left; /* you can do here float:right also */
}
```