# Left & Right sidepanels over a OpenLayers Map in the middle

Tags: html, css, openlayers

I am making a interactive game map using the OpenLayers 3 API. I am want to have four panels in total, two on each side(right & left) and the map shown in the middle, but the map should be located under the sidepanels.
Float, z-index, etc have always been confusing me. I have found a few answers on this topic, but I can never seem to be able to combine the solutions.

**Current CSS of the sidepanels and map:**

```
.map {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;   
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.sidebar {
  z-index:9999;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  outline: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-color: #9ecaed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
.right { float: right; }
.left { float: left; }
```

HTML of the 3 DIVs:

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div> <!-- Map, DIV that goes in the middle -->

<!-- Left sidebars -->
    <div class="sidebar left">
        I removed the content so it is shorter
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar left" style="padding-top: 0px; height: 50%;">
       I removed the content so it is shorter
    </div>

<!-- Right sidebars -->
    <div class="sidebar right">
        I removed the content so it is shorter
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar right" style="padding-top: 0px; height: 50%;">
        I removed the content so it is shorter
    </div>
```

*I have been experimenting with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594703/div-positioning-on-right-and-left-side), but the results are horrific.*

Answer (score 0):

what does your html look like? Keep in mind that `float: right/left` only works for nested html-structures. that means:

```
<div class="outer" style="float:right;">
// this div gives the attribute float to it's inner divs
 <div class="inner"> 
 //this inner div will float right!
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have re-done the website and managed to solve my problem.
Instead of keeping the sidebars outside of the map div, now they are inside.
I used position: `position: relative;` on the map. And `position: absolute;` on the sidebars. I am having trouble with floats, but I will post a diffrent question to solve thoose.